# Accomplishing shareValue/shareBehavior

Tags: rxjs5

I have an Observable that is based on some events and at some point does some expensive computation. I would like to render the results from that Observable in multiple different places. If I naively subscribe to this Observable in two places I will end up doing the expensive computation twice. Here is a code snippet to drive my point home:

```
var s = new rx.Subject();
var o = s.map(x => { console.log('expensive computation'); return x });
o.subscribe(x => console.log('1: ' + x));
o.subscribe(x => console.log('2: ' + x));
s.next(42);
```

The output is:

```
expensive computation
1: 42
expensive computation
2: 42
```

I would like to perform the expensive computation in the map only once. `share` accomplishes this, but it makes it so late-arriving subscribers do not get the current value to render. In previous RxJS versions, `shareValue` allowed late-arriving subscribers to get the current value. However, it appears that this was renamed to `shareBehavior` in RxJS 5 and then removed altogether:

https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/pull/588

https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/pull/712

There is a long discussion in [this issue](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJS/issues/453) where it was decided that they would 'Remove shareBehavior and shareReplay to prevent user confusion.' I don't understand what the potential for confusion was (so maybe that means I am one of the users saved by this decision?).

`publishBehavior` also looks promising but I don't fully understand `publish` and it seems like it adds more complexity than I need or want.

Anyway, I would like to know if there is a recommended way to accomplish this in RxJS 5. The [migration doc](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/MIGRATION.md) doesn't provide any recommendations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some more research I've found that the behavior I've described can be implemented with

[`.publishBehavior(startValue)`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-publishBehavior)`.refCount()`.

This discovery is based on the fact that [`share()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-share) is an alias for `publish().refCount()`. I still don't fully understand `publish()` but this seems to have the desired effect in practice.

Similar is [`cache(1)`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-cache) (which is an alias for `publishReplay(1).refCount()`). It has a similar effect as `publishBehavior(defaultValue).refCount()` except that it does not start with a default value. So if no items have been emitted, new subscribers will not immediately receive a value.